# Using Factory Boy SelfAttribute + relativedelta

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, factory-boy

I'm using Factory Boy in my tests and want to achieve the following:

- Make `first_period_end_date` dependent on `first_period_date` and add 12 months to it.

I'm trying to use `SelfAttribute` in combination with `relativedelta` but the way I'm currently applying it doesn't work. My code:

```py
import datetime

import factory
from dateutil import relativedelta

from somewhere.models import Contract

class ContractFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Contract

    start_date = factory.LazyFunction(datetime.date.today)
    first_period_date = factory.SelfAttribute('start_date')
    first_period_end_date = (
        factory.SelfAttribute('first_period_date')
        + relativedelta.relativedelta(months=12)
    )
```

But in runtime I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'SelfAttribute' and 'relativedelta'
```

So that is apparently not how it's done. But how do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is `LazyAttribute`; `SelfAttribute` is only helpful for copying a field.

You should do:

```py
class ContractFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Contract

    start_date = factory.LazyFunction(datetime.date.today)
    first_period_date = factory.SelfAttribute('start_date')
    first_period_end_date = factory.LazyAttribute(
        lambda self: self.first_period_date + relativedelta.relativedelta(months=12)
    )
```